# How to make button image change with on click anywhere on screen?

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, onclick, sprite

I am very new to Unity and I have trouble understanding on click possibilities with my UI buttons etc.. In my project, I have a button which changes its image whenever I click on it and the way I made it is: I created this script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]

public class OnClickScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int spritenumber=1;
    public Button mybutton;
    public Sprite square;
    public Sprite circle;
    public Sprite triangle;
    public int counter = 1;

    void Start()
    {
        mybutton = GetComponent<Button>();


    }

    public void changeButton()
    {
        if (PAUSESCRIPTE.isPaused == false)
        {
            counter++;
            if (counter == 1)
            {
                mybutton.image.overrideSprite = square;
                spritenumber = 1;
                soundmanagerscript.PlaySound("buttonpress");



            }
            if (counter == 2)
            {
                mybutton.image.overrideSprite = circle;
                spritenumber = 2;
                soundmanagerscript.PlaySound("buttonpress");

            }
            if (counter == 3)
            {
                mybutton.image.overrideSprite = triangle;
                spritenumber = 3;
                counter = counter - 3;
                soundmanagerscript.PlaySound("buttonpress");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I attached this script to my button, selected sprites which I want to use and I added on On Click() function to the button.

Afterwards I decided that I no longer want to change the sprite of my button by clicking on the button itself but rather by clicking anywhere on the screen. I tried using Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) but got no results since I used it incorrectly. Any help on, how to achieve what I want, is very welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class ButtonScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Public objects
    public Sprite[] sprites;

    //Private objects/variables
    private Image buttonImage;
    private int spriteIndex;

    void Start()
    {
        buttonImage = GetComponent<Image>(); // Get the image component of your button
        spriteIndex = 0; // Set the index to 0
        buttonImage.sprite = sprites[spriteIndex]; // Set the image to the first image in your sprite array
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            spriteIndex++; // Increment the index
            if (spriteIndex > sprites.Length - 1) // Ensure that you stay within the array size
            {
                spriteIndex = 0;
            }
            buttonImage.sprite = sprites[spriteIndex]; // Set the image
        }
    }
}
```

However, you need to change the image settings to:

Image Type: simple

Use Sprite Mesh: true

(maybe) Preserve aspect: true

Comment: Thank you, this works for me, but I also have pause button in the same scene and when I click the pause button another sprite changes. I don't know how to prevent that. Could you maybe help?

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to your comment above, I will suggest you to have a button in the background and your pause button above. Then, replace your `Update()` method with an event OnClick() as you did before.

Your pause button will catch the left click and your background button will not.
Be sure to tick **Interactable** in the `Button` component.

Then you can safly remove the `Image` component of your background button, if you don't need it.

---

What it means is you can create (or modify) a class for your pause button

```cs
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class PauseButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    public bool IsMouseOver = false;

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        IsMouseOver = true;
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        IsMouseOver = false;
    }

    // --
    // Your OnClick method
    // --
}
```

**Note: the using eventSystems.**

Now you can use this bool value within a code like `amengelbrecht` send you.

I'll will copy and paste his code from his answer, and add the bool value based on the previous class above.

```cs
public class BackgroundButtonScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Public objects
    public Sprite[] sprites;
    public PauseButton pauseButton;

    //Private variables
    private Image buttonImage;
    private int spriteIndex;

    private void Start()
    {
        buttonImage = GetComponent<Image>(); // Get the image component of your button
        spriteIndex = 0; // Set the index to 0
        buttonImage.sprite = sprites[spriteIndex]; // Set the image to the first image in your sprite array
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !pauseButton.IsMouseOver)
        {
            spriteIndex++; // Increment the index
            if (spriteIndex > sprites.Length - 1) // Ensure that you stay within the array size
            {
                spriteIndex = 0;
            }
            buttonImage.sprite = sprites[spriteIndex]; // Set the image
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow you to click anywhere on your screen except if the mouse is over your pause button. In this case, OnClick from the pause button will be called.

**Be careful**

If your game is is pause and the user left click anywhere but the pause button, depends on how your pause works, the Update() method of BackgroundButtonScript will be called and can lead to `if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !pauseButton.IsMouseOver)`.

Comment: But if I replace Update() with OnClick() on my button, I wont be able to click anywhere on screen to change buttons sprite image but on button itself. Isn't it?

Comment: If the button covers the entier screen, you will be able to click anywhere but the pause button. However, if your wish is to click anywhere else except on Pause button if you have other UI element above the big background button, I will suggest you to take a look at [UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler and IPointerExitHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html) with your pause button.
You can use a bool to check if Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && the bool should return true.